# Revertable property not working properly

Tags: java, javafx

So I created the class, `RevertableDoubleProperty`, and the goal is on every change, to confirm with the user of the change. If `true`, then revert the change. The problem is, I can't just simply ignore the change, because this property is bound (bi-directional) to a spinner value, so ignoring the change would not fix the spinner. I need a way to tell the spinner to reset.

Note the abstraction here, I can't just pass the spinner instance to the property and reset it that way, I need to get a reference to the spinner value property from inside the `RevertableDoubleProperty`.

This has been causing me issues for weeks so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class Test extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Property doubleProperty = new RevertableDoubleProperty();
        doubleProperty.setValue(5);
        ((RevertableDoubleProperty)doubleProperty).setOnPropertyChange(new Callback<Void, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(Void aVoid) {
                final Alert confirm = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
                confirm.setContentText("Are you sure you want to do that?");
                final ButtonType responce = confirm.showAndWait().get();
                assert responce == ButtonType.CANCEL || responce == ButtonType.CLOSE || responce == ButtonType.OK;
                if (responce == ButtonType.CANCEL || responce == ButtonType.CLOSE) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        Spinner<Double> spinner = new Spinner<Double>(0.0, 100.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        spinner.getValueFactory().valueProperty().bindBidirectional(doubleProperty);

        Label label = new Label();
        Bindings.bindBidirectional(label.textProperty(), ((Property)spinner.valueProperty()), new NumberStringConverter());

        FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();
        flowPane.getChildren().addAll(spinner, label);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(flowPane));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    class RevertableDoubleProperty extends SimpleDoubleProperty {
        private DoubleProperty proxyDoubleProperty;
        private Callback<Void, Boolean> onPropertyChange;

        @Override
        public void set(double value) {
            if (onPropertyChange != null && onPropertyChange.call(null)) {//The call returns true if the change wants to be reverted
                //What to do here?
                return;
            }
            if (proxyDoubleProperty == null) {
                proxyDoubleProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
            }
            System.out.println("setting");
            proxyDoubleProperty.set(value);
            super.set(value);
        }

        public void addListener(ChangeListener changeListener) {
            System.out.println("Added listener");
            proxyDoubleProperty.addListener(changeListener);
        }
        public void setOnPropertyChange(Callback<Void, Boolean> onPropertyChange) {
            this.onPropertyChange = onPropertyChange;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you call `changeListener` to reset the value?

Comment: @KDM I thought of that, but I don't have a reference to it. All the stuff needs to be done inside `RevertableDoubleProperty`. I don't think I am doing it right, but my idea was to have two properties, one gets changed by the spinner, and if that is OK, apply it to the second property. The problem is making sure the other dependencies on the property (besides the spinner) don't get any updates unless the change is confirmed.

Comment: IMO, you are handling at the wrong place? Why can't you handle it when the control value is changed?

Comment: @KDM Because I have the property binded to it, the value of the control will instantly change the other property. I need to keep the `valueProperty` of the spinner binded to the second property, but I need to interrupt the bind change.

Comment: I think the problem is notifying the **changer** of the revert, not all the other binds.

Comment: I added a label to show the value of the property.